# Possible to include an html "partial" template (not embedded in js) in Vue 2 router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I know I can do this:

```
const Foo = { 
    template: 
     '<div>bar</div>'
 }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo }
]
```

But I'd rather somehow include an html file like:

```
const routes = [
      { path: '/foo', component: {template: require('foo.html')}  }
    ]
```

...WITHOUT using Webpack, Browserfy or anything like that (I'm trying to keep things simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator Evan You explains here why he didn't want to use templateURLs https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url. So, no what you want isn't possible. Now SSR does give some opportunities to structure your app in the way you are talking about. Especially if you are using something like [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) however, this still includes build steps.